# Xamarin Android TabLayout Badge: Bind Text Mvvmcross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I made a Custom Layout to add a badge to a tab on Android. This badge is a TextView.
How do I bind this component?
It's possible?

My custom badge layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/badgeCotainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notifications_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:minWidth="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#011f7a"
            android:textSize="10sp" 
            android:text="0"
            app:MvxBind="Text ContMaterial"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**My Activity:** use  MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo

```
private void InitTabs()
        {
            var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.materiais_viewpager);
            if (viewPager != null)
            {
                var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo>
                {
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Requisição",
                        typeof(CadastraRequisicaoFragment), ViewModel),
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Materiais",
                        typeof(ListaMateriaisFragment), ViewModel),
                };


                viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(this, SupportFragmentManager, fragments);
            }

            var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.requisicao_tabs);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
             tabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_header_badge);

        }
```

On view Model I used raisedPropertyChanged()
Badge appears normally, just don't change value.
[Tablayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYLTj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box there is nothing in mvvmcross to bind the **content** of a TabLayout when you provide a custom view. You could however try something custom using [MvxFrameControl](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bdaa09299714d94cf3f2c548a465d994c20d52f0/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Binding/Views/MvxFrameControl.cs)

Basically, replace your LinearLayout by the MvxFrameControl, then after

```
tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

inflate your custom view using the BindingInflate method, and set a value to your MvxFrameControl's BindingContext, then set your custom tablayout view with the result that operation.

That might do the trick.

Another way to do it, is to listen to your ViewModel's "PropertyChanged" events in your Activity, and manually make changes to your tab layouts when it applies.

Comment: Thanks Miiite ,
I will have to redo my structure, but I believe it is the only solution.